# React-admin: how to prevent getAll on page load

Tags: react-admin

My use case:
On page load I need to show only filters and empty list.
RA should only make first request to API when user enter anything in one of the filters.

Didn’t found anything related in documentation.
If someone can just pinpoint me correct topic in docs, which I should dig better to achieve what I need, it already will help a lot.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `<List>` component for that, as it makes requests on mount. You'll have to write your own List component and call the API using the `useGetList` hook, as explained [in the documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#usegetlist):

```
import { useGetList } from 'react-admin';
const LatestNews = () => {
    const { data, ids, loading, error } = useGetList(
        'posts',
        { page: 1, perPage: 10 },
        { field: 'published_at', order: 'DESC' }
    );
    if (loading) { return <Loading />; }
    if (error) { return <p>ERROR</p>; }
    return (
        <ul>
            {ids.map(id =>
                <li key={id}>{data[id].title}</li>
            )}
        </ul>
    );
};
```